# Is there a way to separate the items inside selectOneListbox in primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

How do I separate the items inside selectOneListbox or selectManyMenu using a horizontal line ?

Here is my xhtml

```
<p:selectOneListbox id="basic1" value="#{decisionTreeBean.option1}"
                        style=" font-size: 12px;background-color:silver;width:12em; height:10em; border-style:solid !important;border-width:0.5px !important; border-color:grey !important;">
                        <f:selectItems value="#{decisionTreeBean.commentType}" var="X"
                            itemLabel="#{X}" itemValue="#{X}"/>
                    </p:selectOneListbox>
                </p:panel>
                <!-- mtcnc -->
                <p:panel>
                    <h6 style="width: 10.4em; background-color: #ACBECE;">MTCN</h6>
                    <p:selectManyMenu id="advanced1"
                        value="#{decisionTreeBean.option2}" showCheckbox="true"
                        style="font-size: 12px;background-color:silver;width:12em; height:10em; border-style:solid !important;border-width:0.5px !important; border-color:grey !important;">
                        <f:selectItems value="#{decisionTreeBean.mtcns}" var="X"
                            itemLabel="#{X}" itemValue="#{X}" />
                    </p:selectManyMenu>
                </p:panel>
```

[image: Current output]

[image: desired output]

Comment: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/oneMenu.xhtml Take a look in the "advanced" one! you just need one column :)

Comment: Essentially you need to add a style on each row.

Comment: Even in the normal one you can use css...